# Measuring Efficiency of GPU Program

Tags: performance, gpu

I have both serial and parallel program using GPU.
The serial program takes 112.9 seconds to finish.
The parallel program with GPU takes 3.16 second to finish.
Thus, I have the speedup of 35.73.
Can I measure the efficiency of the program using the formula SpeedupTime/NumberOfThread ?
The threads will be 1024

Comment: remember that the GPU is driven by the drivers, the OS and maybe some extra framework. the CPU is a totally different story, plus you are probably comparing a single threaded execution to a framework based implementation .

Answer (score 0):

The efficiency is the ratio of the time on the CPU to time on GPU. You might want to try multicore implementation as well and compare it with GPU implementation.